# Глобальное событие смены раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: c++, winapi, события, интерфейс

Мне нужно знать, какая установлена раскладка клавиатуры пользователя в данный момент (использую в *CALLBACK* функции)

Нашел решение:

```
HKL kbLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL));
```

Это работает, но мне кажется, что не очень хорошо при каждом вызове функции запрашивать у системы текущую раскладку.

---

Нашел ещё одно [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908270), но не совсем понимаю, как его использовать.

В документации написано:

> Чтобы установить этот приемник, получите объект `ITfSource` из объекта `ITfInputProcessorProfiles`, вызвав `ITfInputProcessorProfiles::QueryInterface` с параметром `IID_ITfSource`. Затем вызовите `ITfSource::AdviseSink` с `IID_ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink`.

```
HRESULT hr;
ITfInputProcessorProfiles *pProfiles;
ITfSource *pSource;

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TF_InputProcessorProfiles,
                      NULL,
                      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                      IID_ITfInputProcessorProfiles,
                      (LPVOID*) &pProfiles);

if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return 1;

hr = pProfiles->QueryInterface(IID_ITfSource, (LPVOID*) &pSource);
if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return 1;

// Some code

pSource->Release();
pProfiles->Release();
```

Вроде удалось получить объект `ITfSource`, но дальше непонятно, как вызвать `AdviseSink`

```
HRESULT AdviseSink(
  REFIID   riid,
  IUnknown *punk,
  DWORD    *pdwCookie
);
```

Я так понимаю - в качестве `riid` нужно передать `IID_ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink`,
`pdwCookie` это указатель на переменную, в которую будет записан идентификатор, который позже используется в `ITfSource::UnadviseSink`.

Но что такое `IUnknown *punk`? В примерах кода в интернете туда обычно передают `this`.

То еcть мне нужно создать функцию (или класс?) и писать все это там?

А дальше нужно реализовать метод `OnLanguageChanged`. Буду очень благодарен, если покажете как это сделать.

---

И последний вопрос - мне нужно получать это событие глобально, даже если окно моего приложения не в фокусе. Надеюсь, что это возможно

---

*UPDATE*

Может мне нужно создать класс, наследоваться от `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink`, реализовать методы `OnLanguageChange` и `OnLanguageChanged`, а в `AdviseSink` в качестве параметра `punk` передавать ссылку на объект этого класса? 
<sub>Мысли вслух...</sub>

---

*UPDATE 2*

Спустя некоторое время, получилось реализовать интерфейс `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink` (спасибо @user7860670)

Реализация:

*header*

```cpp
#ifndef LANGAUGECHANGEHANDLER_H
#define LANGAUGECHANGEHANDLER_H

#include <msctf.h>

class LangaugeChangeHandler : ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink {
private:
    ULONG cRef;
    LANGID id;

public:
    LangaugeChangeHandler();
    virtual ~LangaugeChangeHandler();

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLanguageChange(LANGID id, WINBOOL *pfAccept) override;
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLanguageChanged() override;

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject) override;
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void) override;
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void) override;

};

#endif // LANGAUGECHANGEHANDLER_H
```

*cpp*

```cpp
#include "langauge_change_handler.h"
#include <iostream>

LangaugeChangeHandler::LangaugeChangeHandler() {
    cRef = 0;
}

LangaugeChangeHandler::~LangaugeChangeHandler() {
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LangaugeChangeHandler::OnLanguageChange(LANGID id, WINBOOL *pfAccept)  {
    (void) pfAccept;
    this->id = id;
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LangaugeChangeHandler::OnLanguageChanged() {
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LangaugeChangeHandler::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) {
    if (!ppvObject)
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    if(riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink) {
        *ppvObject = this;
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    } else
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE LangaugeChangeHandler::AddRef(void) {
    InterlockedIncrement(&cRef);
    return cRef;
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE LangaugeChangeHandler::Release(void) {
    ULONG ulRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&cRef);
    if (cRef == 0) {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    } else
        return ulRefCount;
}
```

Но я всё ещё не понимаю, как заставить это работать...

Comment: Ну как бы в документации прямо написано: `The ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink interface is implemented by an application to receive notifications when the language profile changes.`

Comment: @user7860670 хорошо, но я всё ещё не понимаю, как реализовать этот интерфейс. (В последнем блоке мои идеи, но я не уверен, насколько это правильно)

Comment: Наследуете класс от него и реализуете виртуальные методы ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink  и IUnknown

Comment: @user7860670 я реализовал все эти виртуальные методы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать дальше. Я уже запутался что от чего надо вызывать, и как вызвать `AdviseSink`. Если передать туда указатель на объект класса - ошибка компилятора. Если скастовать указатель - ошибка выполнения...

Comment: Надо передавать туда указатель на объект класса, каст до IUnknown при этом необязателен.

Comment: @user7860670 извините, я наверно вам уже надоел, но что на этот раз не так ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4Xd41D1a))? Я смог вызвать `AdviseSink` но не получаю уведомлений о смене языка. Даже если вынести `AdviseSink` в отдельный поток, а в основном вызвать `Sleep`.

Comment: Естественно, ведь сразу же вызывается UnadviseSink.

Comment: @user7860670 не могли бы вы привести пример, как привязать *listener* через `AdviseSink`?

Comment: Так у вас же почти правильно сделано - только не надо сразу же его отвязывать вызовом UnadviseSink.